# Кастомный checkbox. Как сменить цвет и вернуть обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css

При отправке формы хочу визуально сделать кастомный checkbox "заблокированным", т.е. пока отправляется форма, сделать синюю птичку чекбокса серой.
Неужели такое нельзя реализовать?

html:

```
<form id="loginform" method="post">
<p>
<label>
Имя пользователя или e-mail
<br>
<input type="text" id="login">
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>
Пароль
<br>
<input type="password" id="pass">
</label>
</p>
<p class="forgetmenot">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="rememberme">
Запомнить меня
</label>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<label>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Войти" class="button">
</label>
</p>
</form>
```

css:

```
#loginform input[type=checkbox]
{
    width: 16px;
    min-width: 16px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #b4b9be;
    color: #555;
    clear: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 16px;
    margin: -4px 4px 0 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0!important;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    transition: .05s border-color ease-in-out;
}

#loginform input[type=checkbox]:checked
{
    background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/16/008BC3/checkmark.png);
    background-size: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#submit").click(function()
    {
        $('#rememberme:checked').css({'background-image':'url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/16/cccccc/checkmark.png)'});

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: index.php,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {"login": login, "pass": pass, "rememberme": rememberme},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) // Обработчик ответа от сервера
                {
                    $('#rememberme:checked').css({'background-image':'url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/16/008BC3/checkmark.png)'});
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) // Обработчик ошибок соединения с сервером
                {
                    console.log(jqXHR.status+" / "+textStatus+" / "+ errorThrown);

                    $('#login-error').fadeIn();
                    $('#login-error').html('<strong>ОШИБКА:</strong> Ошибка соединения с сервером. Повторите попытку позже.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Т.е. по сути хочу изменить картинку чекбокса на такую же, но серого цвета. Однако при замене свойства css через JS чекбокса я получаю фон в виде этой галки, который уже нельзя отключить или включить как чекбокс.
Бьюсь над задачей уже пару часов, как решить ее не знаю. Прошу помочь.

Comment: А зачем столько CSS правил для чекбокса? Половина не нужна, а часть и не работает в разных браузерах

Answer (score 1):

Вам достаточно сделать поля ввода недоступными. Для этого есть специальный атрибут [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_disabled.asp). Если вам его надо отобразить по своему, то добавляем для него стили.

Например ваш код может выглядеть так, кардинально ничего не меняя:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#rememberme:checked').attr('disabled', true);
        
        setTimeout(function(){ // имитация Ajax запроса
          $('#rememberme:checked').removeAttr('disabled');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
#loginform label {
  display: block;
}

#loginform input[type=checkbox] + label {
  display: inline-block;
}

#loginform input[type=checkbox]
{
    width: 16px;
    min-width: 16px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    border: 1px solid #b4b9be;
    color: #555;
    clear: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 16px;
    margin: -4px 4px 0 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0!important;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    transition: .05s border-color ease-in-out;
}

#loginform input[type=checkbox]:checked
{
    background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/16/008BC3/checkmark.png);
    background-size: 16px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}

#loginform input[type=checkbox]:disabled
{
    background-image: url(https://png.icons8.com/metro/16/cccccc/checkmark.png);
}
#loginform input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label
{
    color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form id="loginform" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="login">
        Имя пользователя или e-mail
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="login">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="pass">
        Пароль
      </label>
      <input type="password" id="pass">
    </p>
    <p class="forgetmenot">
        <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme">
        <label for="rememberme">Запомнить меня</label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Войти" class="button">
    </p>
  </form>
```

PS. Тег  переместил, что бы его тоже сделать серым используя в селектору указание на соседний элемент через знак `+`. Его можно использовать и как у вас и как сделал я.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Роман если ответ решил вашу проблему, то можно его отметить как правильный

Answer (score 0):

Единственное решение нашел такое:
1. Создал два стиля для id='rememberme' и для id='rememberme2'.
Разница только в цвете галки.
2. Заменяю checkbox с id='rememberme' на id='rememberme2'.
$('#rememberme2').replaceWith('');
3. После отправки формы обратно заменяю чекбоксы.
Все заработало. Но вариант, по моему, какой-то корявый...